# Good IDE for C++ like xcode for windows with perfect autocomplete?

Tags: c++, xcode, ide

I'm searching good IDE like xcode for Windows ( xcode is IDE with best autocomplete only for Mac ) . 
requirements: This IDE must have perfect autocomplete. For me editor with autocomplete and very good formating style on first place. Do you know it?

Comment: What C++ compiler are you using?` Are you looking to write managed .NET code or regular native C++?

Comment: to Mark: Native C++. to aletanis: I think that Eclipse has very bad autocomplete and formating code style

Comment: @user1779502 - You can customise all of the formatting in Eclipse

Comment: You really shouldn't overlook Eclipse CDT.  It's rather good, if you don't mind installing a compiler yourself (it does not ship with one).

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio would be a good starting point.

There is also a free edition, [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions:

- Visual studio
- Geany gtk (*this one !!!*)
- Code::blocks IDE
- Dev C++ (it doesn't have word completion, but it is a really nice editor)

Links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geany
- http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Main_Page
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio

PS: I highly recommend you to use Geany. It's really reliable, and usable.

Comment: And don't forget to download this Dev-C++ version, not the old one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Comment: Dev C++ has got auto-complete:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B

Comment: Geany isnt for big projects :(. Dev C++ god bless you

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual C++ Express can be used for free and brings a great couple of features.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Netbeans IDE for C/C++. Here is the link to [download](https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=windows&lang=en&option=cpp)